# image preview before upload not working with + image+_row

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I select a image it should preview a image. But when I add my var image_row to onchnage it does not work.

I am trying to make it work with my onclick function `function add_popup_image()`

Codepen Example [Here](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/gpgzEX)

Working single id

```
$("#fileupload_extra_image").change(function(){
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#input-popup-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
}
});
```

Not Working

```
$('#fileupload_extra_image' + image_row).change(function(){
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#input-popup-image' + image_row).attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
}
});
```

**Question:** How Can I Make The `+ image_row` work with my image preview script

Comment: What is `image_row` ? Can include `html` at Question ? What is expected result ? Preview multiple image files , after user selects multiple files to upload ?

Comment: In my codepen example you can see where the image_row in. When create a new row each input file id and img id has its own id. When I choose a file then that file that belongs to that row should be able to preview it in the img that belongs to that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below was your problem:

> **`image_row`** used to return always +1 i.e. if there existed
>   **`input-popup-image1`** then it retrieved **`input-popup-image2`**. For time
>   being I just negated the value before searching for the **`id`**. You just
>   need to take care of the increment of **`image_row`** or the below code would just work fine.

**[Pen Here](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/GJrwge)**

```
$('#fileupload_extra_image' + image_row).on('change',function(){
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var imgrw=image_row-1;
      reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#input-popup-image' + imgrw).attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

To the problem you mentioned in your comments I would suggest to choose the below approach:

[**Updated Pen**](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/aOpQRa)

Add a `classname` for the dynamically added controls `image_preview` and `browse` and then obtain its preview content which will be inside its root parent `.row`. So, this will avoid obtaining with `id` and keeping track of `image_row` value:

```
$(document).on('change','.file',function(){
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var imgpr=$(this).parents('div.row').find('.imgpr')
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(imgpr).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just noticed if I add two new rows at the same time the first image gets placed down in the img preview section below

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Updated the answer.. check and let me know!!

Comment: Working Perfect Thanks For Advice And Help

Comment: anytime... Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#fileupload_extra_image' + image_row).change(function(){
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#input-popup-image' + image_row).attr('src', e.target.result);
            image_row++;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
});
```

The problem is that you update image_row before the callback function for reader actually runs. What's happening is that you add an event listening on fileupload_extra_image + image_row for a change event which is fine. Then, it looks like you do a check for files and you do another event listener for reader on load. Note that this doesn't actually run this line of code yet:

`$('#input-popup-image' + image_row).attr('src', e.target.result);`

It's just simply saying that when reader is done loading, then run it.

Your function then continues and updates image_row which cause the previous line to use a value of 2 instead.

What my fix does is updates image_row only after a successful load is done.